# magento 2.4 get scoped store id (or website id) for button in system config section

Tags: custom-button, magento24, scopeinterface

I need a button in stores > configuration that retrieves product data for the store view selected in the "scope" of the configuration. I created the button but I cannot retrieve the store (or the website) chosen via the "scope" dropdown.

I tried retrieving the current store id via StoreManager, which of course doesn't work because the current store is the admin store and not the system/config scoped store; I also tried using the http request but it doesn't work either:

```
/* \Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http $request */
$scopeId = (int) $this->request->getParam('store', 0); 

---

/* request in controller */
$this->_request->getParam('store');
$this->getRequest()->getParam('store');
```

I also tried using "store_id" in lieu of "store" as the request parameter but none of the above attempts were successful.

So, is there a way to retrieve the scoped store id of the system/config?

This is my button:

```
- Vendor/Module/etc/adminhtml/system.xml

<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Config:etc/system_file.xsd">
<system>
  <section ...>
   <group ...>
    <field id="btn" translate="label" type="button" sortOrder="2" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="1">
     <label>Button</label>
     <frontend_model>Vendor\Module\Block\System\Config\Button</frontend_model>
    </field>
    ...
   </group>
  </section>
 </system>
</config>

- Vendor/Module/Block/System/Config/Button.php
<?php

class Button extends Field
{
    protected $_template = 'Vendor_Module::system/config/button.phtml';

    public function __construct(Context $context, array $data = [])
    {
        parent::__construct($context, $data);
    }

    public function render(AbstractElement $element)
    {
        $element->unsScope()->unsCanUseWebsiteValue()->unsCanUseDefaultValue();
        return parent::render($element);
    }

    protected function _getElementHtml(AbstractElement $element)
    {
        return $this->_toHtml();
    }

    public function getAjaxUrl()
    {
        return $this->getUrl('route/system_config/action');
    }

    public function getButtonHtml()
    {
        $button = $this->getLayout()->createBlock('Magento\Backend\Block\Widget\Button')->setData(['id' => 'btn_id', 'label' => __('Button'),]);
        return $button->toHtml();
    }

}

- Vendor/Module/Controller/Adminhtml/System/Config/Action.php

...

/* \Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http $request */
$storeId = (int) $this->request->getParam('store', 0);  // this returns 0


$result = $this->resultJsonFactory->create();
return $result->setData(['success' => true]);
```

Does anyone know how to get the scoped store id (or website) for this button?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The solution turned out to be very simple indeed! I don't know if it is  the right way but it worked for me. I simply retrieved the store parameter from the block instead of the controller, then I passed the store value as a parameter for my controller:

```
- Vendor/Module/Block/System/Config/Button.php
...
public function getAjaxUrl()
{
    return $this->getUrl('route/system_config/action', ['store' => $this->getRequest()->getParam('store', 0)]);
}
...
```

Now in my controller I can call the store parameter:

```
- Vendor/Module/Controller/Adminhtml/System/Config/Action.php
...
public function execute()
{
  $storeId = $this->getRequest()->getParam('store');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try below code.

```
protected $state;
protected $storeManager;
public function __construct(   
    Context $context,
    \Magento\Framework\App\State $state,
    \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface $storeManager
) {
    parent::__construct($context);
    $this->state = $state;
    $this->storeManager = $storeManager;
}
```

create your function and use below code.

```
public function getCurrentWebsiteId() {
    if ($this->state->getAreaCode() == \Magento\Framework\App\Area::AREA_ADMINHTML) {       
        $request = $this->_request;
        $storeId = (int) $request->getParam('store', 0);
    } else {
        $storeId = true; 
    }
    $store = $this->storeManager->getStore($storeId);
    $websiteId = $store->getWebsiteId();
    return $websiteId; }
```

check with object manager.

```
$storeManager = $this->_objectManager->get('Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface');
$storeId = (int) $this->getRequest()->getParam('store', 0);
$store = $storeManager->getStore($storeId);
$storeManager->setCurrentStore($store->getCode());
```

Comment: Maybe I'm understanding this wrong, but isn't this code doing the opposite of what I need? This code gets the store id from the url (which in my case is already 0 because I'm on backend) and in case nothing is found it returns 0, which is the admin id, not the scoped id of my config section.